# addToMediaCacheExt isn't saving the file

Tags: html, intel-xdk

I'm starting with Intel XDK NEW, and my app needs to download some PDF files from my server.

I've followed the API example (http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/492847). The "update" function works and shows the progress, but the "complete" function is never triggered, and the file never gets stored.

The "update" function:

```
function cacheUpdated(evt) {
            var outString = "";
            outString += "current bytes downloaded: " + evt.current; 
            outString += " total bytes in download: " + evt.total;
            var percentage = evt.current/evt.total
            outString += " percentage downloaded: " + percentage + "%";
            outString += " the unique id is: " + evt.id ;
            outString += "the URL is: " + evt.url;
            console.log(outString);
        }
```

The "complete" function:

```
function cacheComplete(evt) {
            var outString = "";
            outString += "The procedure succeeded (" + evt.success + ") ";
            outString += " the unique id is: " + evt.id ;
            outString += "the URL is: " + evt.url;
            alert(outString);
        }
```

And to start the download:

```
function downloadFile() {
            intel.xdk.cache.addToMediaCacheExt("http://192.168.1.101/apostilas/57/1/apostila1.pdf",
                                               Math.random()*100000); 
            document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.cache.media.update", cacheUpdated, false);
            document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.cache.media.add", cacheComplete, false);
        }
```

Am I doing something wrong?

---

EDIT:  The problem is on the emulator; this works fine on device.

Comment: Are you testing on emulator or app preview? I tested your code, seems to be working on app preview, here is the code I tried: http://jsbin.com/eLIzekey/1/edit

Comment: I tested on App Preview, apparently it's a bug on the emulator...  thanks ^^